# How to set up multistore opencart without using CPanel?

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, online-store

I tried to setup opencart without using CPanel( Setting it up in CPanel can be done [this way](http://doc.opencart.com/display/opencart/Creating+a+multi-store)).
I already have opencart(lets call it the main shop) running at < mydomain >.com 
What I did is the following:

1. created a separate subdomain eg. shop2.< mydomain >.com,
2. made the shop2 subdoamin point to the same ip as the < mydomain >.com (the main shop)
3. created a virtual host(apache) for the shop2 subdomain and its document root point to the same as the existing main shop.
4. Created a new store in opencart, and set the store url as shop2.< mydomain >.com ( With or without this step won't change my problem described below.

The problem is that shop2.< mydomain >.com now is exactly the same as < mydomain >.com , for example, if a product is disabled from the existing opencart, it is disabled from the shop2 as well.

Similar question is asked on the [opencart forum](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=81265) but no answer has been provided.

My environment is: Ubunbu, Apache.

Answer (score 0):

So this question has an incorrect title as You already did set up a multistore. Instead of this You should be asking `How to disable a product on just one store within a multistore installation?`, shouldn't You?

The problem is clear and the answer too - You cannot do this by enabling/disabling the product/category, etc. The `multistore` feature allows You to have only **one** database while You can set a product (or category or whatever) to show on store 1 to store X.

If You disable the product, You disable it for all stores.

**If You want a product to be shown only at store 2 but not at store 1, check/uncheck the appropriate checkboxes within a product detail form at tab Links -> option Stores.** By unchecking `Default` and checking e.g. `Store 2` You set the product to be shown only at store 2 - **but the product has to be enabled**. Same way for categories, manufacturers, etc.