# Setting up a Multistore on Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I read through this post [Set up a Multistore on Opencart](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/opencart-set-up-multiple-stores/) trying to setup multistore for my opencart website and followed every step in the post, created a sub domain and pointing it to the store domain itself and using a different theme for my sub domain.

But my subdomain keeps displaying the store theme, even though i changed it in settings -> store -> template and it changed successfully.

I read through this post on stackoverflow [How to set up multistore opencart without using CPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997485/how-to-set-up-multistore-opencart-without-using-cpanel/16014148#16014148)
but still wasn't able to solve my problem.

Is there anything else i need to do or know, to setup a working multistore?

Am using opencart Version 1.5.5.1

Please any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Do you have SEO enabled? Also please tell the format of domain urls. Is that like domain.com and domain.com/store1/ ?

Comment: The reason is very probably that the store from subdomain is rewritten/redirected/aliased to the main store and it acts also as a main store. In this case You have just two main stores on different subdomains (*www* and *other*). You probably did something wrong when configuring alias for main domain from your subdomain.

Comment: @Sankar V...thanks for the reply, i have SEO url enabled in my main domain, under settings -> server, this is the format of my domain url is (http://store.com ) while my sub domain is (http://shoe.store.com) or do i have to create a fresh installation in a sub folder like: public_html/shoe/new_installation ?

Comment: @shadyyx...thanks for reply also, This is my subdomain info          Domain (shoe.store.com) document-root (/public_html) Redirection(not redirected)

Comment: In `index.php`, debug the code under `// Store`. That'll help you.

Comment: what is your actual version right now ?